# Vue 3 Options -> Composition Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Why isn't the "startDate" reflected within the v-text field of my v-date-picker after mounting when after setting startDate with the response from the getApplication function? My child component never seems to receive the updated "startDate" data (it yields 'Empty' due to selectedDate being null). It therefore doesn't show the date from the database in v-text-field after mounting in the date-picker component. Is reactivity lost somehow? Perhaps because I'm going from options api parent component to composition api child component?

Vue 3 and Vuetify v3.4.7 Date Picker.

**Parent Component**

```js
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-row>
            <v-col>
                <datepicker
                label="Start Date"
                v-model="startDate"
                color="primary"
                ></datepicker>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
    import datepicker from '@/components/util/datepicker.vue';
    export default {
        components: {
            datepicker
        },
        data () {
            return {
                startDate: null,
            }
        },
        mounted:function(){
            this.getApplication();
        },
        methods: {
            getApplication: async function() {
                await this.$axios.get('/api/application')
                .then((response) => {
                    this.startDate = response.data.startdate;
                    console.log("StartDate: "+this.startDate); // produces: StartDate: 2023-12-20T06:00:00.000Z
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

**Child Component (datepicker)**

```js
<template>
    <v-menu v-model="isMenuOpen" :close-on-content-click="false">
      <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
        <v-text-field
          :label="label"
          :model-value="formattedDate"
          readonly
          v-bind="props"
          variant="outlined"
          density="comfortable"
          hide-details
        ></v-text-field>
      </template>
      <v-date-picker v-model="selectedDate" hide-actions title="" :color="color">
        <template v-slot:header></template>
      </v-date-picker>
    </v-menu>
  </template>
  
  <script setup>
  import { ref, computed, watchEffect} from "vue";
  
  const { label, color, modelValue } = defineProps([
    "label",
    "color",
    "modelValue",
  ]);
  const emit = defineEmits(["update:modelValue"]);
  const isMenuOpen = ref(false);
  const selectedDate = ref(modelValue);
  
  const formattedDate = computed(() => {
    return selectedDate.value ? selectedDate.value.toLocaleDateString("en") : "Empty";
  });

  watchEffect(() => {
    selectedDate.value = modelValue;
  });
  
  </script>
  <style>
  .v-overlay__content:has(> .v-date-picker) {
    min-width: auto!important;
  }
  </style>
```

**UPDATE W/ SOLUTION (thanks to moon)**
This update provides a utility component that can be imported to create a textfield/menu to click and select a date from a v-date-picker in Vuetify 3. I have removed the headers in the calendar and I make it so the calendar hides after a date selection. The date can be stored as a UTC date while the textfield will have a MM/DD/YYYY formatted version of the date.

**Parent Component (updated)**

```js
<template>
    <v-container>
        <v-row>
            <v-col>
                <datepicker
                label="Start Date"
                v-model="startDate"
                color="primary"
                ></datepicker>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </v-container>
</template>

<script>
    import datepicker from '@/components/util/datepicker.vue';
    export default {
        components: {
            datepicker
        },
        data () {
            return {
                startDate: null,
            }
        },
        mounted:function(){
            this.getApplication();
        },
        methods: {
            getApplication: async function() {
                await this.$axios.get('/api/application')
                .then((response) => {
                    this.startDate = new Date(response.data.startdate); // this needs to be converted to a date object
                    console.log("StartDate: "+this.startDate); // produces: StartDate: 2023-12-20T06:00:00.000Z
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

**Child Component (datepicker updated)**

```js
<template>
    <v-menu v-model="isMenuOpen" :close-on-content-click="false">
      <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
        <v-text-field
          :label="label"
          :model-value="formattedDate"
          readonly
          v-bind="props"
          variant="outlined"
          density="comfortable"
          hide-details
        ></v-text-field>
      </template>
      <v-date-picker v-model="selectedDate" hide-header title="" :color="color">
        <template v-slot:header></template>
      </v-date-picker>
    </v-menu>
  </template>
  
  <script setup>
  import { ref, computed} from "vue";
  
  const emit = defineEmits(["update:modelValue"]);
  const props = defineProps([
    "label",
    "color",
    "modelValue",
  ]);
  let isMenuOpen = ref(false);
  
  const formattedDate = computed(() => {
    return selectedDate.value ? selectedDate.value.toLocaleDateString("en") : "";
  });

  const selectedDate = computed({
    get: () => {
      return props.modelValue;
    },
    set: (val) => {
      emit('update:modelValue', val);
      isMenuOpen = ref(false);

    },
  });
  
  </script>
  <style>
  .v-overlay__content:has(> .v-date-picker) {
    min-width: auto!important;
  }
  </style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two bugs in your code below, label, color, modelValuethe all lost reactive ,and emit never be used

```js
const {
  label,
  color,
  modelValue
} = defineProps([
  "label",
  "color",
  "modelValue",
]);
const emit = defineEmits(["update:modelValue"]);

//modified 1
const props = defineProps([
  "label",
  "color",
  "modelValue",
]);
// to use like this: props.modelValue

//modified 2
const formattedDate = computed({
  get: () => {
    return selectedDate.value ? selectedDate.value.toLocaleDateString("en") :
      "Empty";
  },
  set: (val) => {
    emit('update:modelValue', val)
    //when the date-picker changed by user ,the startDate of parent component  will changed 
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this moon! I'm going to accept this answer because my biggest issue was getting the data to the child component which your modified 1 fixed. I did use your modified 2 syntax but swapped it for the selectedDate which is what was needed. I posted my working solution based on your suggestions in my edit above.